# Convert "HH:MM AM/PM" varchar column to time in Teradata

Tags: sql, time, format, teradata

I need to convert the following varchar column to a 24 hr database time format in Teradata.

```
1:00 AM
6:45 PM
10:15 AM
9:30 PM
9:45 AM
8:30 PM
1:15 PM
```

Any pointers to existing solutions will be very helpful. I have not been able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the leading zero if missing and then cast using a format:

```
cast(lpad(col,8,'0') as time(0) format 'HH:MIBT')
```

Comment: The `BT` part of the format is for AM/PM, yes?  I have always wondered what the heck that stands for.

Comment: The `T` is for AM/PM,. but the `B` is Blank, a space `' '` is simply ignored, Cobol style :-)